# Manually increment a CSS counter

Tags: css, counter

I'd like to be able to reset a CSS counter to 20, starting after the 20th item. The goal is to have two list-items that have an accompanying "20" number, and then to continue the list as normal.

```
ol {
  list-style-type: none;
  counter-reset: quote-counter;
}
ol .list-item__inner::before {
  content: counter(quote-counter);
  counter-increment: quote-counter;
}
```

Something like this maybe (this of course does not work)?

```
li:nth-child(20) {
    counter-reset: quote-counter 20;
}
```

Comment: Or you could actually decrement the counter by 1 in 20th `li` element's `:after` pseudo like [here](https://jsfiddle.net/r91wsakf/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the [`counter-reset`](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-lists-3/#propdef-counter-set) property will set the counter before `counter-increment` gets called so you want to `reset` to `n - 2` to get the repeat you want:

```css
ol {
  list-style-type: none;
  counter-reset: quote-counter;
}
ol li::before {
  content: counter(quote-counter) ". ";
  counter-increment: quote-counter;
}

li:nth-child(6) {
    counter-reset: quote-counter 4;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>first</li>
  <li>second</li>
  <li>third</li>
  <li>fourth</li>
  <li>fifth</li>
  <li>sixth</li>
  <li>seventh</li>
</ol>
```

You need `n - 2` rather than `n - 1` because of the order that `counter-reset` and `counter-increment` must be applied.  Quoting from the specification:

> Inheriting counters must be done before resetting counters, which must be done before setting counters, which must be done before incrementing counters, which must be done before using counters (for example, in the content property).

Since the reset happens before the increment, we need to move the counter back one more place so the increment will put it at the correct number.

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you! Would you mind elaborating on why I need to `reset` to `n - 2` though?

Comment: `counter-reset` gets invoked before `counter-increment` - so to get the same number to repeat, you need to set the counter to `desiredNumber - 1` (or in this case `nth-child - 2`).  Changing the last selector to `li:nth-child(6)::before` should let you use `quote-counter: n - 1` (e. g. `quote-counter 5`).

Comment: Actually, belay that point - found the details in the spec - I'll update the answer.